# This is a question from set theory. What exactly is a graph of some function and how can we decide if a set is the graph of another function.

Tags: functions, relations

Suppose I give you a set R subset **2x2**. How can we decide if R is the graph of some function 2implies2?

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not very clear... A function must satisfies the restriction that for every "input" we have a single "output: $x^2$ is a function, while $\sqrt x$ is not.